# ViewPager goes below the display?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So I'm trying to make an app have a Tabbed Activity and I'm using this code for the ViewPager.

activity_result_screen_tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.proyo.wshindsight.ResultScreenTab">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
                android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                android:id = "@+id/toolbartext"
                android:text = "Results"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The code below is one of the tabs in that Activity.

fragment_text.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.TextFragment"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/vlayout">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And in fragment_text.xml TextViews are dynamically added to the LinearLayout.

Now here's the problem. When enough TextViews are added, so that we reach the bottom of the display, it will not show a few of them. The ScrollView works just normally, but I think the ViewPager is not working correctly.

[Here's a picture of how it it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I01Uw.png) It should continue till 15, like the one above it, but for some reason it stops at 10.

[Here's a picture of the same page, with scrollbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al6gl.png) If you look at the scrollbar, it is already at the bottom of the screen, while it still scrolls on till 10.

Finally, when checking out the Preview option in Android Studio on the ViewPager component, it also showed that it's going below the screen.

So I highly suspect the fault being in activity_result_screen_tab.xml, but I really wouldn't know what could be wrong there.

EDIT: Still don't have an answer, someone answered to change the layout_heights of fragment_text, but that didn't help either.